# Having a global queue (or list) that is available to all threads

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to write a script which consumes data over the internet and places the data which is pulled every n number of seconds in to a queue/list, then I will have x number of threads which I will create at the start of the script that will pick up and process data as it is added to the queue. My questions are:

1. How can I create such a global variable (list/queue) in my script that is then accessible to all my threads?
2. In my threads, I plan to check if the queue has data in it, if so then retrieve this data, release the lock and start processing it. Once the thread is finished working on the task, go back to the start and keep checking the queue. If there is no data in the queue, sleep for a specified number of time and then check the queue again.

Comment: This is *exactly* what [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) is for: *"The `Queue` module implements multi-producer, multi-consumer queues. It is especially useful in threaded programming when information must be exchanged safely between multiple threads."*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) and pass it to multiple threads:

```
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue

def task(queue):
    while True:
        item = queue.get()  # blocks until an item is available
        # process item

queue = Queue()
t = Thread(target=task, args=(queue, ))
t.daemon = True
t.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your app to be really multithreaded then consider using standalone queue (like activemq or zeromq) and consume it from your scripts running in different os processes because of GIL (with standalone queue it is very easy even to use it in network - plus to scalability).